# vocab_model.docvecs.doctag_syn0.npy not generated after saving doc2vec model

Tags: python, numpy, gensim

Following is the code :-

```
modelDoc = Doc2Vec(size=300, window=5, dm=0, dbow_words=1, hs=0, negative=10, alpha=0.05, min_count=20,
                       workers=cores, sample=1e-5, seed=0, iter=10)
    modelDoc.build_vocab(finalSent)
  
    modelDoc.save(save_model)
```

my version :
gensim==3.8.1
numpy==1.16.2

after saving the model
only vocab_model file is generated

`vocab_model.docvecs.doctag_syn0.npy` is not generated.
what is the use of this file and does it is necessary to generate this file.

Answer (score 0):

Were there any errors shown during the `.save()`?

Does the saved file load & work as expected? (In this case, since the original model wasn't trained, does it train alright as if the save-then-load hadn't happened?)

If there's no error, & it works, it's fine.

(Wha's the reason  that a file of this name was expected, and its absence was a concern?)